# Activity content transition doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I want to start `Activity` with content transition. But the content transition doesn't work. Why and how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
class PolishStartActivity : AbsActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initContentTransition()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_polish_start)
    }

    private fun initContentTransition() {
        window.apply {
            requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)
            enterTransition = TransitionSet().apply {
                addTransition(Slide(Gravity.TOP).addTarget(R.id.tvBooksTitle).addTarget(R.id.tvBooksDescription))
                addTransition(Fade().addTarget(R.id.cvSearchBox))
                // addTransition(Fade()) only this transition works fine 
                duration = 1000L
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I start my `Activity` with `ActivityOptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts and experiments, I found the fix for this problem.

On my root `ViewGroup` (in my case it is `ConstraintLayout`) add this line:

```
android:transitionGroup="false"
```

Yes! Now you can set `targets` for transitions and it will be work!

Comment: that's incredible!

Answer (score 0):

Put **initContentTransition()** before **super.onCreate()**;

```
    class PolishStartActivity : AbsActivity() 
   {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
        {
            initContentTransition()
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_polish_start)
        }
       ..................
       ..................
}
```